# Formula to see if you're on track of monthly budget

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm not sure where to post this question but I thought here would be a good spot. What would be a Google Sheets formula to see if I am on track to stay within my allocated monthly allowance? I'm not very good at math and I've tried to come up with a solution but I'm not sure how & I've looked it up and done research but I still am not sure of the right formula to use. I've tried using something like `(actual - goal)/ABS(goal)+100%` but that returns a small number and I'm sure that's not correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: `=(goal-actual)/goal` then format the cell as a percentage.  this will give you the percentage of budget you have left, and go negative when you are over.

Comment: You are currently added `1` to your formula.  If you want to take that route, multiply by 100.  However, @ScottCraner's answer will give you the desired answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, maybe some example numbers could help.

Let say you have:

```
goal = 1000
actual=150
```

Using your formula

```
actual - goal = -850
```

I think what you should do is to find (goal - actual) instead => 850

Then you can do your percentage of use:

```
(goal - actual) / goal * 100 => 85%
```

So on your sheet, if your goal is in the cell A1 and your actual in cell A2, type something like (this is excel-like I believe):

```
=($A$1 - $A$2) / $A$1 * 100
```

Hope it is helping.